# App Crashing when loading Custom Class SKSpriteNode to SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am creating SKSpriteNode Programmatically with its own SKSpriteNode class. I am wondering how I can add this SKSpriteNode to the scene. My app keeps crashing when I try to addChild() in the didMove() function of my Scene Class.

```
class ChaosScene: SKScene {
var dragonNode: Dragon!

     override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
            dragonNode.createDragon()
            addChild(dragonNode)
        }
    }

class Dragon: SKSpriteNode {    
    var dragonNode: SKSpriteNode!
    func createDragon() {
            // Create Dragon
            dragonNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dragon_2_fly_001")
            dragonNode.name = "dragon"
            dragonNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)

            let actionMove = SKAction.move(
                to: CGPoint(x: -1000 ,y: dragonNode.position.y),
                duration: 2.0)
            dragonNode.run(actionMove)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the crashlog say? Is `dragonNode` already instantiated when you call `addChild` ?

Comment: @Koen Thread 1: fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional Value

Comment: @Koen do i need to call the createDragon function in the scene?

Comment: Well, before you call addChild.

Comment: @Koen I do call it and I receive the same error

Comment: `dragonNode` is nil, you need to create that one first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're not actually creating anything.

```
class ChaosScene: SKScene {
    var dragonNode: Dragon!

     override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        dragonNode = Dragon()
        addChild(dragonNode)
    }
}
```

you have to initialize your SpriteNodes before you can add them to the scene

```
class Dragon: SKSpriteNode {  

    var dragonNode: SKSpriteNode!

    init() {

        super.init(texture: nil, color: .clear, size: CGSize.zero)

        // Create Dragon
        dragonNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dragon_2_fly_001")
        dragonNode.name = "dragon"
        dragonNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 50)
        addChild(dragonNode)

        let actionMove = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -1000 ,y: dragonNode.position.y), duration: 2.0)
        dragonNode.run(actionMove)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean dragonNode.createDragon() ? Because I have tried this and still receive the same error.

Comment: I receive this error : Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'Dragon!'

Comment: You also need to update createDragon() to return a dragonNode.

Comment: @FrankBoccia this isn't the best way to subclass SKSpriteNode. give me a sec to write up and edit to my answer

Comment: @RonMyschuk Thank you I appreciate the help, I am trying to learn. Make my code as best as possible.

Comment: @RonMyschuk So the init, creates a new SKSpriteNode?

Comment: @FrankBoccia as you get more advanced into Spritekit game dev you'll find that a subclassed SpriteNode (such as Dragon) very rarely just consists of a SpriteNode. It often has children, actions, particles etc. All i've done is create an empty shell spritenode to hold your dragon sprite. this allows you to have all the properties that go along with a spriteNode (vs subclassing it as an SKNode)

Comment: @RonMyschuk awesome, do you recommend like positioning the sprite in his own class, or should I use the scene and position the dragon there?

Comment: both. position the dragon sprite in the Dragon class in relation to other objects in the sub class (ie. if you had a fire ball as part of the subclass you might position the dragon to the left, and the fireball to the right all inside the subclass) then in the Scene you position the dragon where you want him in relation to all other objects in the scene. Now it doesn't matter where you put him n the scene the fire will always been on his right.

Comment: @FrankBoccia glad to help. As always, if this answer was helpful or correct please remember to mark it as so, so that others can benefit from this.

Comment: @RonMyschuk we must add to your code because we used init() first!

Comment: @FrankBoccia those kind of edits to answers aren't necessary. there are lots of bits of code that get left out in answer to keep the answers more focused and concise.